# Consulta con mysqli_query y while da error

Tags: php

Intento hacer una consulta a la base de datos donde arroja varias filas pero hay algo que me da error, ¿donde lo estoy haciendo mal?

Mi consulta:

```
function get_items($numero)
{ 
    $con = conectarBD();

    if(!$con)
    {
        echo "fallo al conectar a la bd";
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mitabla WHERE ARTICULO LIKE '%".$articulo."%'";

    $resultado_BD = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $fila_consulta = $resultado_BD;

    $con->close();

    return $fila_consulta;

}
```

Y la muestro asi:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
    echo $row['COMPONENTE'];
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el error que te da a la pregunta?

Comment: De dónde sale `$articulo` y dónde usas `$numero`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema es que **haces la lectura fuera del contexto en que se obtienen los datos**. O sea, tú no puedes meter el resultado de `mysqli_query` en una variable y retornar esa variable, como de hecho haces en el código de la pregunta. ¿Por qué? Porque cuando haces una consulta lo que recibes es **un puntero hacia esos datosm u recurso**, el cual sigue activo **mientras estás en ese contexto**. En este caso el contexto es la función `get_items`. Por lo tanto los métodos `fetch`, que sirven para recorrer el puntero (leer los datos en el recurso) tienen que ser usados *in situ*, sea para mostrar los datos ahí mismo con `echo` o sea para meterlos en una variable y devolver esa variable, en caso de necesitar los datos en otro contexto.

Además, cuando cierras la conexión, el puntero se cierra con ella y no tienes ya acceso a los datos. Pero aunque no la cierres, no te funcionará retornar el resultado de `mysqli_query` a otra parte por lo dicho anteriormente.

Entonces, si necesitas llamar a `get_items()` para que te retorne datos de la base de datos, tienes que leer los datos dentro de la función, llenar una variable con ellos y devolver esa variable.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
function get_items($articulo)
{ 
    $con = conectarBD();
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo "fallo al conectar a la bd";
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mitabla WHERE ARTICULO LIKE '%$articulo%'";
    $resultado_BD = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $mData=array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_BD))
    {
        $mData[]= $row;
    }
    $con->close();
    return $mData;
}
```

En el ejemplo se recibe `$articulo` como parámetro de la función, asumiendo que es el dato que necesitas para el `LIKE`.

También, hemos llenado la variable  `$mData` con los resultados en el contexto en que obtuvimos los resultados de la consulta. Ahora, podemos hacer una prueba de la función:

```
$datos=get_items(3);
foreach ($datos as $row) 
{
    echo $row['COMPONENTE'].PHP_EOL;
}
```